# Scala overriding def with val throws NPE

Tags: scala

I am learning `Scala` and in `Programming in Scala 3rd Ed`, `Ch 10, Page 225`, section `Overriding methods and fields`, it says

> The uniform access principle is just one aspect where Scala treats
>   fields and methods more uniformly than Java. Another difference is
>   that in Scala, fields and methods belong to the same namespace. This
>   makes it possible for a field to override a parameterless method. For
>   instance, you could change the implementation of contents in class
>   ArrayElement from a method to a field without having to modify the
>   abstract method definition of contents in class Element, as shown in
>   Listing 10.4:

My code based on the example is

*with def*

```
abstract class Element {
  def contents: Array[String]

  val height = contents.length

  val width = if (height == 0) 0 else contents(0).length
}


class ArrayElement(contnts: Array[String]) extends Element {
  def contents: Array[String] = contnts
}

// --
val ae = new ArrayElement(Array("hello", "world"))
ae.height
ae.width
```

I get

```
ae: ArrayElement = ArrayElement@7cd3ba8e
res0: Int = 2
res1: Int = 5
```

*with def overridden as val in ArrayElement*

```
abstract class Element {
  def contents: Array[String]

  val height = contents.length

  val width = if (height == 0) 0 else contents(0).length
}


class ArrayElement(contnts: Array[String]) extends Element {
  val contents: Array[String] = contnts
}

// --
val ae = new ArrayElement(Array("hello", "world"))
ae.height
ae.width
```

I get `NPE` as

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at #worksheet#.Element.<init>(scratch.scala:4)
    at #worksheet#.ArrayElement.<init>(scratch.scala:10)
    at #worksheet#.ae$lzycompute(scratch.scala:15)
    at #worksheet#.ae(scratch.scala:15)
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(scratch.scala:14)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Class-level fields are initialized before anything else, meaning that `null` is assigned. You can make the declaration a `lazy val` and it won't be initialized until it's called. That's the reason the def works. A better way though, instead of creating a class public field shadowing the private constructor field, is to just make the constructor field public like this:

```
class ArrayElement(val contnts: Array[String]) extends Element {}
```

Since there's a parent class at play here too, it would be good to mark it as overriding;

```
class ArrayElement(override val contnts: Array[String]) extends Element {}
```

If this is going to be a stateless data container class though, the best option is to make it a `case class`, which (among several other things) has public-by-default fields.

```
case class ArrayElement(override val contnts: Array[String]) extends Element
```

This is much more idiomatic scala and it will provide you with a value-based `equals`, `hashCode`, pattern matching, simpler construction (no need to `new`)

Comment: True. A simple rule of thumb is to never reference an abstract `def` inside a `val`, as there are no guarantees the `def` is going to have any value by the time the `val`s are instantiated. @Daenyth, I edited your comment to provide another option